# Select specific record using case as if

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Attempting to select unique data from a table that contains multiple records for the same ID.

I am basically looking to pull security_name data for all security ids present in the option_price_view.

Security_name has multiple records for a single securityid, the latest for some having the ticker "ZZZZ" or null. I want to condition it so that if there is only one record, grab it, whatever it may be. If there are multiple, pull the one with the latest date and a ticker is not null or <> "ZZZZ"

the security_name table has the following fields:
Securityid, ticker, date, issuerdescription

I have tried multiple nested selects to try to filter out "ZZZZ" or null values but I do not understand the syntax for IF number of records = 1, select it, else select the next record ordered by date desc.

```
select * from security_name 
where securityid in 
(
    select distinct securityid 
    from option_price_view
)
and ticker <> "ZZZZ"
and ticker is not null
```

What happens here is that any records in security_name that do not have multiple records, will not populate.

UPDATE =================================================

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgBeR.png)

[Security_Name table result for that securityID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snQCp.png)

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: To clarify, please direct me to a topic that I should learn to implement this. I have not used CASE before and I am currently learning the many ways to use it.

Comment: what if there are 2 records, one with 'zzzz' and one null -- but no additional records?

Comment: @avery_larry These records do not exist. We used to use ZZZZ to delist a record, now we use blank values (null). Basically, everything before this change will be zzzz and everything after will be null

Comment: @DaleBurrell figuring out how to paste screenshots

Comment: @SQLNoob Actually SO prefers data in text form, that way it can be copy and pasted out to build test tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you want to include the rows where ticker is null or 'ZZZZ' if they are the ONLY row.  If so, I have come up with the following.

This is **UNTESTED** and may have syntax errors.

Comments are inline.

```
select * -- You will probably want to enumerate the relevant columns because this will also return the rown number column
from ( -- I use 2 paremeters for order by so that ticker is null and ticker = 'zzzz' are the lowest priority
   select SN.*, row_number() over ( partition by securityid
                              order by case when isnull(ticker,'ZZZZ') = 'ZZZZ' then 1 else 0 end,
                              date desc ) rownum
   from security_name SN
   inner join ( -- I like to inner join but this could be in the where clause "where in" or "where exists"
      select distinct securityid
      from option_price_view
   ) OPV on OPV.securityid = SN.securityid
) SN_a -- This completes the subquery returning everything ordered by our desired priority
where rownum = 1 -- This limits the output to the single highest priority record for each securityid
```

Comment: This query is... beautiful. So much too google. Thank you good sir ! I'm sorting through 2.1 billion records so this took some time but from first glance, this worked!

Comment: @SQLNoob based on your comment, this line `order by case when ticker is null then 2 when ticker = 'ZZZZ' then 1 else 0 end,` can be reduced to this `order by case when isnull(ticker,'ZZZZ') = 'ZZZZ' then 1 else 0 end,`

Comment: So here is a scenario where it did not work:

Security_name table select:
==================================================
securityid cusip          date                          ticker
101017 00444610 1996-01-02 00:00:00 ACET  
101017 00444610 2000-11-28 00:00:00 ACET  
101017 00444610 2017-01-11 00:00:00 ACET  
101017 00444610 2019-04-03 00:00:00
======================================================

Comment: query result:
101015 2006-06-30 00:00:00 00440310 AACE     ACE CASH EXPRESS INC         COM                  6153 2006-06-30 20:35:00 2006-06-30 20:35:00 1
101017 2019-04-03 00:00:00 00444610          ACETO CORP.                  ORDINARY SHARES      5122 2019-04-03 16:03:00 2019-04-03 16:03:00 1
101021 2000-11-28 00:00:00 00461P10 ACLA     ACLARA BIOSCIENCES INC       COM                  3826 2001-06-08 11:04:00 2003-02-26 18:00:00 1

The ticker is blank for Aceto Corp even though a not null ticker exists in security_name

Comment: I'm sorry about this formatting, I know I can use a backtick to format but it isn't working as intended

Comment: I added screenshots to the original post

Comment: You said null or 'ZZZZ'.  You said nothing about '' (which is not the same as null).  Try `case when isnull(ticker,'ZZZZ') in ('','ZZZZ') then 1 else 0 end`  Untested but I think that will eliminate null AND 'ZZZZ' AND ''.

Comment: Or if you have '' and you do not have null it can just be `case when ticker in ('','ZZZZ') then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: How interesting that a blank value isn't automatically null.. I will add and spot check. Also discovered there is '?' in the ticker field as well. Added that to the condition

Comment: Out of curiosity, if there are 2 successive 'ZZZZ' or one 'ZZZZ' and one blank and then a third ticker that actually exists, will this be able to handle that? Since I am not yet educated on the over, partition clauses, I am having trouble understanding the logic. Halfway into a youtube video to understand

Comment: The query basically uses the ORDER BY clause to determine what you think is the best match.  Once the ORDER BY clause is done, then the outer select only chooses the rows where the row number = 1, which is the highest priority or best match.  If you have multiple rows with 'ZZZZ' then they will all get the same for the first part of the order by.  The second part of the order by would then sort all of those records by date descending so you will get the newest of all the 'ZZZZ', '', '?' etc. rows.  You can add additional "steps" to the ORDER BY clause to further sort out your best match.

Comment: You can use `select distinct ticker from option_price_view order by ticker` to get an ordered list of all the ticker values.  Usually the oddball values will be at the top or bottom.

Comment: aaahh I see what is going on. Thank you @avery that is immensely helpful!

Comment: Option_price_view does not have the column ticker, security_name does.. But I understand how to implement that now ! Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the most performance query, but I think it does what you want:

```
select top (1) with ties sn.*
from security_name sn
where sn.securityid in (select opv.securityid from option_price_view opv) and
      sn.ticker <> 'ZZZZ'  -- gets rid of NULL values too
order by row_number() over (partition by sn.securityid order by date desc);
```